# Efficiently get Vec<Ref<'a, T>> from Ref<'a, BTreeSet<T>>

Tags: rust, reference, time-complexity, refcell

I have a `Ref<'a, BTreeSet<T>>` and I would like to get the references of its content as `Vec<Ref<'a, T>>`.
One method to do this is:

```
fn get_refs<'a, T: Ord>(btree: Ref<'a, BTreeSet<T>>) -> Vec<Ref<'a, T>> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for e in btree.iter() {
        result.push(Ref::map(Ref::clone(&btree), |t| t.get(&e).unwrap()))
    }
    result
}
```

[A running example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a771acba2abbbb25d0b34093f0d1eaa)

Now let `n` be the size of `btree`.
Because getting a value from a binary tree takes `O(log(n))` and because iterating through a binary tree takes `O(n)` this method has time complexity `O(n log(n))`.

Even though doing this in with `&'a BTreeSet<T>` and `&'a T` instead of `Ref<'a, BTreeSet<T>>` and `Ref<'a, T>` takes `O(n)` (Because we only need to collect the references iterated in an array). An example of the method using plain references is the following.

```
fn get_refs<'a, T: Ord>(btree: &'a BTreeSet<T>) -> Vec<&'a T> {
    btree.iter().collect()
}
```

[A running example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5525db2f4d92480f5df682747b503f3e)

My question is:
Given `Ref<'a, BTreeSet<T>>` is there a way to get `Vec<Ref<'a, T>>` in `O(n)` time complexity?

Comment: If you care that much about complexity it might be appropriate to have both data structures from the beginning and use the set to get items and to use the vector to iterate them. When you add an item, you do so for both structures, so adding is still amortized O(log N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to take a reference to a `Ref` instead of a `Ref`:

```rust
fn get_refs<'a, T>(btree: &'a Ref<BTreeSet<T>>) -> Vec<&'a T> {
    btree.iter().collect()
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c29d5fd2d1459ad4bed0f2680161e7ff)

This way, the `Ref` can live longer than the life of your function, which means you can return references that borrow the `Ref` without dealing with borrowing a temporary.

Note that this means you can just work with `&'a BTreeSet<T>` instead and not even have to work with `Ref`s, so your [original code with references works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c28080514fe9fa5d92eb435fa8316a0a).